# Can I customize MS office ribbon to my own style?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office, ribbon

Can I do a lot more changes in UI of MS Office ribbon in my 'WPF,C# application'?

1- Change the background color of this ribbon

2- change the button size to any size?

3- Other style related changes

See image for clarification of my question
[image: See image for clarification of my question]

Comment: have you read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx and come to conclusion thatt the document does not satisfy your hunger?

Answer (score 2):

I use the ribbon only from VBA, not C#, but imagine it does not matter in this case.

1- Change the background color of this ribbon.

Short answer, no.  Possibly changing the overall windows theme or something like that may affect the colour, but there is nothing in the XML model like `groupBackground="Blue"`.

2- change the button size to any size?

Again, no.  Buttons come in two sizes, to accommodate 16 x 16 and 32 x 32 images.  The length of the text in the button, if any, will also influence the button's size

3- Other style related changes.

The MS Office ribbon is not that feature rich.